# plot lines representing date ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
MIN           MAX        GENDER
01/01/2002    17/12/2010   MAN
04/05/2012     07/08/2018  WOMAN
```

I'm trying to plot for each row a line starting at `MIN` and ending at `MAX` as in the image.

I'm trying `ggplot2`

```
date <- c("2002-01-01", "2010-12-17", "2012-04-05", "2018-08-07"
    group <- c("Man", "Woman")
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(date, group))
    library(tidyverse)
    df %>%
    mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% #convert to date
  group_by(group, date)  #group
```

[image]

But can't find how to get the difference between the dates to draw the lines.

Comment: What is the Y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get the Data

```
txt <- "MIN           MAX        GENDER
01/01/2002    17/12/2010   MAN
04/05/2012     07/08/2018  WOMAN"

dta <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header =TRUE)
dta$MIN <- as.Date(dta$MIN, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
dta$MAX <- as.Date(dta$MAX, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

### The Plot

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(GENDER) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -GENDER) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(GENDER, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = GENDER)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_date(breaks = c(dta$MIN, dta$MAX)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

### Output

[image: Output]